# SSL Error when connecting with paho mqtt client -

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I have a bit of code that connects fine with the paho mqtt client from my OSX bash shell.  When I attempt to run the same code directly from within PyCharm, I receive the error below - the exception seems to happen within wrap_socket.

I'm new to these tools, but I believe that both environments are pulling Python 2.7.11 from /usr/bin/python (from a homebrew installation).

I'm wondering if someone can suggest what differences I should be looking for that would explain this behavior.

**[SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:590)**

Comment: I would just double check to make sure PyCharm is using the same interpreter you think it should be. Some information that may help is [View available interpreters](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/5.0/configuring-available-python-interpreters.html?origin=old_help#d23263e119).

Comment: Can you show the code?

Answer (score 0):

As Cory hints in the comment above, I didn't really have my interpreter correctly selected.  I was configuring the "Build, Execution, Deployment" Python Console - and not the project's interpreter (as I should have been).  Once I configured the project interpreter to point at my homebrew installation of python, all was well.  Thanks much -